# Prediction (sample based) vs. population confidence interval

Tags: statistics

Imagine we measure the length of a sample of widgets and, as we do not know the true population values, we compute the sample mean and standard deviation. We then construct a 95% prediction interval using those values. I understand that we cannot expect 95% of the observations to fall in this prediction interval because the estimation error of the mean and standard deviation will cause it not to match exactly the true population-wide confidence interval. However, I believe that we can actually expect **fewer** than 95% of the observations to fall in the prediction interval. I'd see why if the only source of uncertainty was on the sample mean. But when there's also estimation error in the standard deviation, the prediction interval could, in principle, be larger than the full population-wide confidence interval and include it completely. If this is true, it would actually include **more** than 95% of the observations, wouldn't it?

Comment: The "$95\%$ confidence interval" is typically something like a [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) for the mean, with the aim that the methodology produces an interval which includes the mean $95\%$ of the time it is used.   With a large sample, this interval will usually be narrow and most of the individual observations will be outside the interval.  You may be confusing this with a [prediction interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval) for future observations.

Comment: @Henry. You're right, I'm confused about the terminology. I've edited the question accordingly. However, I still don't see why fewer than 95% of the future observations should lie in the prediction interval.

Comment: What makes you "believe that we can actually expect fewer than 95% of the observations to fall in the prediction interval"?

Comment: It was supposed to be the correct answer in a multiple choice quiz